# Why is the super class method called?

Tags: java

```
class One { 
  public void doThing(One o) {System.out.println("One");}
}

class Two extends One{
  public void doThing(Two t) {System.out.println("Two");}
}

public class Ugly {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Two t = new Two();
    One o = t;
    o.doThing(new Two());
  }
}
```

Result : One

```
class One { 
  public void doThing(One o) {System.out.println("One");}
}

class Two extends One{
  public void doThing(Two t) {System.out.println("Two");}
}

public class Ugly {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Two t = new Two();
    One o = t;
    t.doThing(new Two());
  }
}
```

Result : Two

I know that at runtime, even though the object reference is of the super class type, the actual object type will be known and the actual object's method will be called. But if that is the case, then on runtime the `doThing(Two t)` method should be called but instead the super class method `doThing(One o)` is called. I would be glad if somebody explained it

In the second piece of code it prints "Two".

**Question :** when calling from the super class reference it is calling the `doThing(One o)`
when calling from the sub class reference it is calling the `doThing(Two o)`

**NOTE:**  I know that i am over loading and not over riding. i have edited my question for better clarity.

Comment: you are overloading, not overriding

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4

Comment: @nachokk : if you had posted this link as the answer, i would have opted your as an accepted answer. i never thought of looking up the java specs. Thx man.. dat was of wonderful help..

Comment: no matter, but what you were looking  is how dynamic method invocation works.

Comment: i went through the whole doc.. :)

Comment: Consider making your answer an an answer! not in the question..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the compile time the compiler searches the class `One` for the method `doThing(Two t)` but since there isn't a method with that signature it starts widening its search and finds `doThing(One o)`. Then it holds the binary file with the descriptor `one parameter whose type is One : void`. At runtime since the object invoking the method is of type `Two`, in class `Two` it looks for the method that matches the descriptor and doesn't search for the method `doThing` that accepts an object of `Two` as it considers the descriptor in the binary file it links the call to the method `doThing(One o)`.

the java specs was of great help explaining this. [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) is the link

Comment: @downvoter: Please let me know why the answer is not useful.. so that i can improve it, if possible.

Answer (score 12):

The method `doThing()` have different method signature in `One` and `Two`.

```
One.doThing(One one)
Two.doThing(Two two)
```

Since, the signature isn't matched, `Two.doThing(Two)` doesn't Override `One.doThing(One)` and  since `o` is of type `One`, `One.doThing()` is called.

Also to be noted that `One.doThing(One)` can take `instance of Two` as an argument for `One.doThing(One)` as `Two extends One`.

> Basically, "@nachokk - You are Overloading, not Overriding"

In first scenario, when you did

```
Two t = new Two();
One o = t;
o.doThing(new Two());
```

So, `o` is an instance of `One` and `Two.doThing(Two)` isn't available to `o` thus calls `One.doThing(One)`

In second scenario,

```
Two t = new Two();
One o = t;
t.doThing(new Two());
```

`t` is an instance of `Two` and thus `Two.doThing(Two)` is called.

Comment: That's a good point but if he overloads the metod in class `One` then `doThing(Two two)` will get called!.

Comment: thx for the reply.. but i am very well aware of the fact that i am not over riding.. please see my edited question.. maybe my previous question was unclear....

Comment: @BlackPanther See my updated answer, hopefully, it's much understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You are just overloading,as you said

```
    Two t = new Two();
    One o = t;
    o.doThing(new Two());
```

Even though the actual object at runtime is a Two object and not a One object, the 
choice of which overloaded method to call (in other words, the signature of the 
method) is NOT dynamically decided at runtime. Just remember, the reference
type (not the object type) determines which overloaded method is invoked!

When you call doThing() method with Two object argument,you will invoke One super class doThing() method.The doThing() method needs a One object, and Two IS-A One. 
 So, in this case, the compiler widens the Two reference to a One object, and 
the invocation succeeds. The key point here is that reference widening depends on 
inheritance, in other words the IS-A test.

Comment: so are you saying that even though the object that is invoking the method is of type `Two` the method that will be chosen and bound by the reference that calls it?

Answer (score 1):

The excelent book SCJP for Java 6 states:

> If a method is overridden but you use a polymorphic (supertype)
>   reference to refer to the subtype object with the overriding method,
>   the compiler assumes you’re calling the supertype version of the
>   method.

So basically with using supertype for reference you're telling compiler to use supertype method.

Comment: i don't get this.. the method is not overriding. Could you give me an example of what you are saying with code?

Answer (score 0):

This is something trick question
Your statment 
`One o = t;` 
I think , you are assuming that class One 'o' is equal to Class Two 't', which is not actually equal to class Two 't' 
as Class Two 't' is inherited from Class One, so it will assign the base class One in your case, 
So variable 't' is reference of the class One and hence will call the method of class One.

 More over you create one more class named as ClassC class and try to set your statement
`ClassC c= new ClassC ()` 
 and then 
`One o = c;` 
You will get an error... hope the answer your question.